# How to delete grepl-unmatched column values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called mydf. I want to look for the presence of `c.change` values in `Clinvar_Type`. If present, I want to delete everything in `grepl("Clinvar, colnames(mydf))`.

This is my data:

```
mydf <- structure(c("chr1:8045045:A:G", "chr1:8045045:A:G", "chr1:8045045:A:G", 
"chr1:17314702:C:T", "chr1:17314702:C:T", "chr1:17314702:C:T", 
"c.501A>G", "c.441A>G", "c.414A>G", "c.2775G>A", "c.2658G>A", 
"c.2790G>A", "NM_007262.5(PARK7):c.501A>G (p.Ala167=)", "NM_007262.5(PARK7):c.501A>G (p.Ala167=)", 
"NM_007262.5(PARK7):c.501A>G (p.Ala167=)", "NM_022089.4(ATP13A2):c.2790G>A (p.Ser930=)", 
"NM_022089.4(ATP13A2):c.2790G>A (p.Ser930=)", "NM_022089.4(ATP13A2):c.2790G>A (p.Ser930=)", 
"single nucleotide variant", "single nucleotide variant", "single nucleotide variant", 
"single nucleotide variant", "single nucleotide variant", "single nucleotide variant", 
"HGNC:16369", "HGNC:16369", "HGNC:16369", "HGNC:30213", "HGNC:30213", 
"HGNC:30213"), .Dim = 6:5, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("VarID_build37", 
"c.change", "Clinvar_ Name", "Clinvar_ Type", "Clinvar_ HGNC_ID"
)))
```

Result I want:

```
    VarID_build37       c.change    Clinvar_ Name                                Clinvar_ Type               Clinvar_ HGNC_ID
 "chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.501A>G"  "NM_007262.5(PARK7):c.501A>G (p.Ala167=)"    "single nucleotide variant" "HGNC:16369"    
"chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.441A>G"     
"chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.414A>G"     
"chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2775G>A" 
"chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2658G>A" 
"chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2790G>A" "NM_022089.4(ATP13A2):c.2790G>A (p.Ser930=)" "single nucleotide variant" "HGNC:30213"
```

Comment: `grepl` returns a logical vector, so just negate it? `!grepl(...)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas That did not work for me. I was vectorizing across the column.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think you are not getting my point. I need to look for values like `"c.501A>G"` from `c.change` column in `Clinvar_ Name ` column. If present, don't delete Clinvar col values, else delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution. (you can replace `""` with `NA` if you prefer).

```
mydf[,-(1:2)][!apply(mydf,1,function(x) grepl(x["c.change"], x["Clinvar_ Name"])),] <- ""

    VarID_build37       c.change    Clinvar_ Name                                Clinvar_ Type               Clinvar_ HGNC_ID
[1,] "chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.501A>G"  "NM_007262.5(PARK7):c.501A>G (p.Ala167=)"    "single nucleotide variant" "HGNC:16369"    
[2,] "chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.441A>G"  ""                                           ""                          ""              
[3,] "chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.414A>G"  ""                                           ""                          ""              
[4,] "chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2775G>A" ""                                           ""                          ""              
[5,] "chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2658G>A" ""                                           ""                          ""              
[6,] "chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2790G>A" "NM_022089.4(ATP13A2):c.2790G>A (p.Ser930=)" "single nucleotide variant" "HGNC:30213"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Base R solution using `mapply()` with `grepl()`:

```
idx <- mapply(function(x, y) !grepl(x, y, fixed = TRUE), mydf[, "c.change"], mydf[, "Clinvar_ Name"])
```

Or you can use `stringi::stri_detect_fixed()` because it is vectorized over string & pattern:

```
idx2 <- stringi::stri_detect_fixed(mydf[, "Clinvar_ Name"], mydf[, "c.change"], negate = TRUE)

identical(unname(idx), idx2)
[1] TRUE
```

With either option, use the index, select the columns, and assign `NA` to them. Also, keep in mind that a blank character string `""` is different from a missing value `NA` in R. Hope this helps!

```
mydf[idx, 3:5] <- NA

mydf
     VarID_build37       c.change    Clinvar_ Name                                Clinvar_ Type               Clinvar_ HGNC_ID
[1,] "chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.501A>G"  "NM_007262.5(PARK7):c.501A>G (p.Ala167=)"    "single nucleotide variant" "HGNC:16369"    
[2,] "chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.441A>G"  NA                                           NA                          NA              
[3,] "chr1:8045045:A:G"  "c.414A>G"  NA                                           NA                          NA              
[4,] "chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2775G>A" NA                                           NA                          NA              
[5,] "chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2658G>A" NA                                           NA                          NA              
[6,] "chr1:17314702:C:T" "c.2790G>A" "NM_022089.4(ATP13A2):c.2790G>A (p.Ser930=)" "single nucleotide variant" "HGNC:30213"
```